# COUNTIFS in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have been battling to get the COUNTIFS formula right for the below. I need to count the number of events per day. How many times did the event happen between 2021-04-20 14:24:54 and 2021-04-20 19:16:13.

absolutely losing it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: result]

Isn't that difficult ! :)
Try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A,">="&B2 , A2:A,"<="&C2 )
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This does make sense. I do however have like 4 years worth of records. Will I have to add a "From" (B2) and a "To" (C2) for each day over 4 years?

Comment: Cant B2 and C2 in the formal be replaced by =COUNTIFS(A2:A,">="&2021/04/20 00:00:01 , A2:A,"<="&2021/04/20 23:59:59 )

Comment: Try:   `=COUNT(FILTER(A2:A,day(A2:A)=day("04/20/2021")))`   or `=index(COUNTIF(day(A2:A), "="&day("04/20/2021")))`   ... same result

Comment: getting somwhere now

Answer (score -1):

below the formula gives a calculation of 22 but should actually be 16.

i am definitely still doing something wrong.

it first gave me an error "Iterative calculation" so i switched on under file-settings.

updated the date format then arrived at the wrong calculation

[image: calculation]